# Oracle date with tine

Tags: oracle, date

I'm having some difficulty trying to generate a start date at 1PM and INCREMENT by 2 days 15x. Can someone help me out.

```
select DATE '2023-02-22'+ INTERVAL '0 13:00:00' DAY TO SECOND  + NUMTODSINTERVAL ( LEVEL * 2, 'DAY')) FROM    dual
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi';

Session altered.

SQL> select (trunc(sysdate) + 13/24) + (level * 2) result
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 15;

RESULT
----------------
24.06.2023 13:00
26.06.2023 13:00
28.06.2023 13:00
30.06.2023 13:00
02.07.2023 13:00
04.07.2023 13:00
06.07.2023 13:00
08.07.2023 13:00
10.07.2023 13:00
12.07.2023 13:00
14.07.2023 13:00
16.07.2023 13:00
18.07.2023 13:00
20.07.2023 13:00
22.07.2023 13:00

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```